# Hide Swift "Will never be executed" warning

Tags: xcode, swift, clang, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I've got some code that is generating warnings like so:

> *code path*.swift:9:13: warning: will never be executed
>
> ```
>        fatalError()
>        ^
> ```
>
> *code path*.swift:9:13: note: a call to a noreturn function
>
> ```
>        fatalError()
>        ^
> ```

The compiler output doesn't give any `-W` arguments I can use to silence these in my source file. How can I stop these warnings?

Please note this is testing code and everything is working as designed - **removing the lines complained about is not a solution**

Comment: As far as I know, the Swift compiler currently has no options to suppress warnings. – A (short) typical *self-contained example* would be helpful in order to find alternative solutions for you.

Comment: Select the line(s) and press `⌘/`. To reenable the line(s) repeat the procedure.

Comment: @MartinR I'm trying to create a self-contained example, but without success. I'm in a Nimble assertion, so as long as you can add Nimble (e.g. with CocoaPods), you can see it like so: `expect{ fatalError() }.to(throwError())`

Comment: @vadian as mentioned, the lines are a necessary part of the test. Please see the last part of the question (in bold)

Comment: At least regarding the first warning I believe the compiler. If the code will never be executed it isn't relevant for the test ;-)

Comment: @vadian The compiler is wrong. It is executed.

Comment: @Dov: I am not familiar with Nimble. But `fatalError()` *terminates the program*, it does not throw an error. Therefore `expect { fatalError() }` will never return.

Comment: @MartinR I know. I'm working on a `throwAssertion()` matcher, but it's not  done yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swift compiler does not have an option to suppress warnings
(as far as I know). The only chance is to *avoid* the warnings.

In your particular case I don't have a full explanation
for the warning, but a possible workaround. As you said in the comments,
the problem occurs with the Nimble framework in

```
expect{ fatalError() }.to(throwError()) // Warning: Will never be executed
```

Here, `{ fatalError() }` is a closure of type `() -> Void`,
and `expect` ultimately calls the `Expression` initializer

```
public init(expression: () throws -> T?, location: SourceLocation, isClosure: Bool = true)
```

which takes a closure of type `() throws -> T?` as the first parameter.
The problem is now related to the *optional* return type `T?`.

This can be stripped down to the following *minimal self-contained example*:

```
let cl1 : () -> Void  = { fatalError() } // No warning
let cl2 : () -> Void? = { fatalError() } // Warning: Will never be executed
```

Only the second line generates a warning.
I *assume* that the compiler creates some wrapper code to convert
the `Void` return type from `fatalError()` to `Void?`, and then warns
that the wrapper code is never executed.

As a workaround, you can make the closure type explicit as

```
let cl3 : () -> Void?  = { _ -> Void in fatalError() } // No warning
```

or assign the closure to an intermediate variable:

```
let fatalClosure = { fatalError() }
let cl4 : () -> Void? = fatalClosure // No warning
```

This can be applied to your case:

```
expect {
    _ -> Void in fatalError()
}.to(throwError())
```

But note that `fatalError()` – when called – terminates the program
immediately. There is no chance to "catch" that termination.

Comment: Apparently the warning does not appear anymore in Xcode 9.2.